# Previous File Location Lookup

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, file

While prepping for the switch to a new computer, I made the dreadful decision to move files from the "All My Files" Finder view to a new folder. All of the files moved to the new folder, but left the old folders in all of the previous locations (now with no files in them). I've completely lost the file structure that organized all of the files into something meaningful.

I didn't realize my mistake until it was too late to "Undo". Is there any way to look up the previous location of a list of files?

- OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
- no Time Machine or other backups

Comment: No, file location isn't something that's tracked and without any form of backups, that would have path recursion, you're out of luck. At least you have the files and didn't loose them. You might want to consider using Time Machine going forward!

Answer (score 1):

> No, file location isn't something that's tracked and without any form of backups, that would have path recursion, you're out of luck. At least you have the files and didn't loose them. You might want to consider using Time Machine going forward!

Source: [comment by user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/241694/previous-file-location-lookup#comment296975_241694)

Answer (score 0):

If you moved the file to Trash, as opposed to moving the file to another directory, then you can right-click on the file in Trash, and choose "Put Back" in the menu.